# How to show the velocity of free motion is constant in Galileo's relativity principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, velocity, galilean-relativity

Picture below is from Landau & Lifshitz's Mechanics.  How to get the red line from green line?

> [image]

Comment: because  $~\frac {\partial L(v)}{\partial v}~=$ constant. $~L=\frac{m\,v^2}{2}~$ what you get ?

$~m\,v=C~,v=\frac{C}{m}=~$constnat

Comment: @Eli  From $~\frac {\partial L}{\partial v}~=$ constant, I get $L= Cv$ where $C$ is constant. But I don't know how to get red line.

Comment: @lanse7pty you are confused, that derivative is constant in time, not with respect to the velocity, Lagrange equations tells you that it's only constant with respect to time

Comment: Related (same part of LL) https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/776982/226902

Comment: What about this explanation? $f(v_i) = \frac{\partial L(v^2)}{\partial {v_i}}$ is injective in $v_i$. Therefore if it's constant $v_i$ is constant too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite generally, the Langrangian of a single particle in three spatial dimensions can be a function of the variables time $t$, position $\mathbf{r}$ and velocity $\mathbf{v}= \dot{\mathbf{r}}$.
In the special case of an *inertial frame*, no instant of time, no point in space and no direction in space is preferred with respect to another one. This property is meant by saying that an inertial frame can be characterized by homogeneity of time and space and isotropy of space. As a consequence, the Lagrangian of a free point particle in an inertial frame must be independent of $t$ (homogeneity of time) and $\mathbf{r}$ (homegeneity of space). Remains a dependence on the velocity $\mathbf{v}$. But as there is no preferred direction in space, the Lagrangian can only depend on $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$, leading to $L= L(\mathbf{v}^2)$ (c.f. eq. (3.1) in the book of Landau-Lifshitz). In that case, the Euler-Lagrange equations reduce to $$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{v}^2)}{\partial v_i} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{v}^2)}{\partial v_i}= {\rm const.} \quad {\rm for} \, \,   i=1,2,3. $$ Employing the chain rule, one obtains $$\frac{\partial L(\mathbf{v}^2)}{\partial v_i} =L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) \, \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}^2}{\partial v_i} = 2 L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) v_i,$$  as $\partial \mathbf{v}^2 /\partial v_i = \partial (v_k v_k) / \partial v_i = 2 v_i$.

Thus, the Euler-Lagrange equations lead to $L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) v_i = {\rm const.}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and finally to the desired result $\mathbf{v} ={\rm const.}$ (c.f. eq. (3.2) in the book).

Note that the form of the function $L(\mathbf{v}^2)$ is not yet determined by homogeneity of space and time and isotropy of space alone. This demands the additional requirement  that the action integral should be invariant under a velocity transformation (Galilei transformation in the nonrelativistic limit and Lorentz transformation in the general relativistic case, respectively). In the nonrelativistic (NR) case, this additional requirement leads to $L_{\rm NR}(\mathbf{v}^2) = a \mathbf{v}^2$ with the constant of proportionality denoted by $a= m/2$. In the general (relativistic) case, the Lagrangian is given by $L(\mathbf{v}^2)= -m c^2 \sqrt{1- \mathbf{v}^2/c^2}$, which reduces indeed to $L(\mathbf{v}^2) = -m c^2 + m \mathbf{v}^2/2$ in the nonrelativistic limit $|\mathbf{v}| <\!\!< c$. (The constant term $-mc^2$ does not affect the equations of motion.)

Edit: In view of the comment below, let me demonstrate the step from $\frac{d}{dt} \left( L^\prime (\mathbf{v}^2) v_i\right) =0$ (for $i=1,2,3$) to $d \mathbf{v}/dt=0$ in full detail. As $$ 0= \frac{d}{dt} \left( L^\prime (\mathbf{v}^2) v_i \right) = 2 L^{\prime \prime}(\mathbf{v}^2)\, \mathbf{v}\!\cdot \!\dot{\mathbf{v}} \, v_i + L^\prime (\mathbf{v}^2) \dot{v}_i = \left( 2 L^{\prime \prime} (\mathbf{v}^2) v_i v_j +L^\prime (\mathbf{v}^2) \delta_{i j} \right) \dot{v}_j $$ (summation convention used in the last step), this equation implies $\dot{\mathbf{v}}=0$ if we can show that the determinant of $M_{ij}= 2 L^{\prime \prime}(\mathbf{v}^2) v_i v_j + L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) \delta_{ij}$ does *not* vanish. As the determinant is given by $$\det M = \left(2 L^{\prime\prime}(\mathbf{v}^2) \mathbf{v}^2 + L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) \right) \left(L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2)\right)^2,$$ we have to rule out the cases $L^\prime (\mathbf{v}^2) =0$ and $2 L^{\prime \prime}(\mathbf{v}^2) \mathbf{v}^2 +L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2)=0$. $L^\prime (u)=0$ (with $u=\mathbf{v}^2$) implies $L(u) = C$ with a constant $C$, which does not represent a physically acceptable Lagrangian. The differential equation $2 L^{\prime \prime}(u) u + L^\prime (u)=0$ has the solution $L(u) = a u^{1/2} +b$ with constants $a,b$, corresponding to the Lagrangian $L(\mathbf{v}^2) = a |\mathbf{v}|+b$ with the equation of motion $\frac{d}{dt} (\mathbf{v}/|\mathbf{v}|)=0$. This Lagrangian can be ruled out as it does not admit a Galilei (Lorentz) invariant action integral.

Comment: Thanks , but I still don't know why $L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) v_i = {\rm const. }$   means  $\mathbf{v} ={\rm const.}$ ?

Comment: Because the first green line,   namely,  $\partial L({\rm v}^2) / \partial \rm v= {\rm const.}$ ?

Comment: @lanse7pty I have added a detailed discussion of the step from $L^\prime(\mathbf{v}^2) \mathbf{v} =$ constant of motion $\Rightarrow \, \mathbf{v} =$ constant of motion in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $$f(v(t))=\text{constant}$$ in time, then either $f$ is constant for all the velocities that the the particle has during it's motion, or or the velocity itself is constant in time, because if the velocity changes
$$v(t_1)\ne v(t_2)$$ then
$$f(v(t_1))\ne f(v(t_2))$$

I guess Laundau here just assumes that the gradient of the Lagrangian with respect to velocity is non-trivial (non constant), so hat we must be in the second case.

Comment: If $\partial L / \partial v = constant \ne 0$, then Lagrangian with respect to velocity is non-trivial. Therefore, it is the second case.  Am I right ?

Comment: @lanse7ptythe lagrangian is non trivial, but $\partial L/\partial v$ could be trivial. Landau is trying to treat the most general case.

Comment: I know Lagrangian is non trivial, and $\partial L/\partial v$ is constant. But I need $\partial L/\partial v \ne 0$ to get  that $L$
 is not constant for all the velocities. So I assume  $\partial L / \partial v = constant \ne 0$.

Comment: But why constant? It can be any function; in the case of the classical classical lagrangian (in one dimension) $L=1/2\cdot mv^2$ you have $\partial L/\partial v = mv$, not a constant

Comment: Sorry, I really be confused. In Landau's book, there is $\partial L/ \partial \mathbf v = {\rm const.}$. But in your case, $\partial L/\partial v = mv$ (I think your $v$ is equal to $\mathbf v$ ), I really don't know how to understand it.

Comment: "Constant" is a relative word, you need to specify with respect to what variable, in this case, integrating the euler lagrange equation you get that that function is constant IN TIME, no with respect to $v$

Answer (score 1):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
Another solution

From EL you obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \b v}\right)^T=\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial \b v}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \b v}\right)^T}_{\ne 0~(\text{if}~L=L(\b v^2))}\frac{d \b v}{dt}=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
 \frac{d\b v}{dt}=0\quad ,\b v=\text{constant}~\surd$$

**Notice**

$$\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \b v}\right)^T\bigg|_{~\b v\mapsto \b v(t)}=\text{constant}$$

thus the factor of $~\frac{d\b v}{dt}~$ is the mass matrix $\left(~\b M\,\frac{d\b v}{dt}\right)=\b 0$

---

**Example**

$$L=-m\,c^2\,\sqrt{1-\frac{\b v^2}{c^2}}$$

$$\b M=\frac{m\,c^3}{(c^2-\b v^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Why  $\frac{\partial}{\partial {\rm v}}   (\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\rm v}} )^T \ne 0$ ?   In fact, from the first green line, I think it is equal to $0$.

Comment: @lanse7pty according to Newton the Eom's $~m\dot v=0~$ thus this is the "mass" part it can't be zero.

Comment: @lanse7pty see more information